# How does Kickstarter charge in the background?

Tags: ios

I was curious about how Kickstarter charged their users in the background. As in, how are users charged when a campaign reaches its goal?

The reason I'm asking is because I would like to make an app (iOS) where a user pledges to give money for an item and once the price of the item is reached, everyone who pledged is charged, and the money goes to the correct account. If anyone could let me know how Kickstarter does this or tell me how to accomplish, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: The moment you say 'background', it means there is a server involved. The app has no part in actually charging the users. It is the server application which must be supported by a database which stores the pledges as well as credit card information and carries out the transactions the moment the campaign reaches it's goal. The APP is just the interface, which lets the user communicate with the server.

Comment: Ok. Do you know of any tutorials on how to do this or could you point me in the right dorection? I don't really have an idea of what to do next. I would like to use parse as my server if that's possible.

Comment: This is almost more of a business practice/workflow question than programming.

Comment: I guess my question is really just would I do this process in php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It'll all be done on a back-end server somewhere and the back-end server would send a push to the customer to inform them it has happened

To accomplish it yourself you'll need to create a server that stores enough customer details to be able to charge them and then the server can automatically do it for you when the time has come i.e. when there are enough pledges

Comment: Ok. Do you know of any tutorials on how to do this or could you point me in the right dorection? I don't really have an idea of what to do next. I would like to use parse as my server if that's possible.

Comment: Not really my area of expertise.. I just sent an edit request where I have changed the tags to more relevant languages etc. hopefully someone will be able to help you out